# Were 6 million units of the TRS-80 Model 100 portable computers sold?

Tags: consumer-products

According to Wikipedia, the [TRS-80 Model 100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS-80_Model_100) sold 6 million units.

This number seems very high. In fact, our former Dear Leader, Jeff Atwood [wrote](https://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/183466722626502656):

> wow, they sold six million portable TRS-80s? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS-80_Model_100 I'm calling {{citation needed}} on that.

Is there documentary evidence to support the 6 million unit figure?

Comment: [PC World](http://www.pcworld.com/article/136242/the_most_collectible_pcs_of_all_time.html) (slide 19) agrees with Jeff: "The sales estimate of 6,000,000 quoted above comes from Wikipedia, and sounds high: It may include foreign models marketed by other companies, and/or descendants such as the Model 102 and Model 200."

Comment: Interesting; if you sum the trs-80 column [here](http://jeremyreimer.com/postman/node/329) (which cites sources on page), looks less than one quarter of that. That isn't the model 100 specifically.

Comment: @Marc, sounds awfully like an answer...

Comment: I wasn't sure it was up to this site's level of citation for good answers...?

Comment: @MarcGravell That data comes from ArsTechinca (good), but it is for the US only (bad). The TRS-80 had clones in Europe.